# How to mass remove manually assigned accounts in Territory Management?

Tags: territory-management, territory

Is there a way to mass remove manually assigned Accounts in a Territory Model ?

Note, currently there no assignment rules in the Territory model. This is a sandbox.

[image: r]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ObjectTerritory2Association](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_objectterritory2association.htm) has this information and a field called `AssociationCause`

> The means by which the record was associated with the territory. User interface field label is Method.
> Possible values are:
>
> - Territory2AssignmentRule—Territory assignment rule association
> - Territory2Manual—Manual association

As such, you should be able to just do the following in anonymous apex (or just query to use dataloader):

```
List<ObjectTerritory2Association> manualTerritoryAssignments = [
    SELECT Id 
    FROM ObjectTerritory2Association 
    WHERE AssociationCause = 'Territory2Manual` AND SobjectType = 'Account'
];

delete manualTerritoryAssignments;
```

You can also filter by the `Territory2` if you just want to remove certain territory assignments.